Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "fn", e is undefined
So i'm trying to install npm package manager for a legacy php code base. I was able to successfully install some libraries that my codebase was using via npm. And im compiling them via webpack, but upon testing, when i import one of my modules, i get Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "fn", e is undefined.
Although i researched online and it seems majority of the problem might be from jquery not being initialized, i made sure it was and its globally available. But its still not working.
Below is my webpack config
const path = require('path');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    core: './src/core/index.js',
    ui: './src/ui/index.js',
    data: './src/data/index.js',
    visualization: './src/visualization/index.js',
    utilities: './src/utilities/index.js',
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    clean: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf|svg)$/,
        use: ['file-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: require.resolve('jquery'),
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'expose-loader',
            options: {
              exposes: ['$', 'jQuery']
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin()],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css',
    }),
    // new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    //   $: 'jquery',
    //   jQuery: 'jquery',
    // }),
  ],
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'source-map',
};

And this is the file where i import the modules (ui/index.js)
import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap';

import 'bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.css';
import 'bootstrap-select';

import 'bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css';
import 'bootstrap-datepicker';

import 'bootstrap-combobox';

import 'bootstrap-filestyle/src/bootstrap-filestyle';


import 'bootstrap-multiselect/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css';
import 'bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js';

import 'bootstrap-sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.css';
import 'bootstrap-sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js';

import 'bootstrap-switch/dist/css/bootstrap3/bootstrap-switch.css';
import 'bootstrap-switch';

import 'bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.css';
import 'bootstrap-tagsinput';

import 'bootstrap-validator/dist/validator.js';


import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';

import 'jasny-bootstrap/dist/css/jasny-bootstrap.css';
import 'jasny-bootstrap/dist/js/jasny-bootstrap.js';

import 'jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css';
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker';

In which i made a test.php file to test it out
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Full Feature Test</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./dist/ui.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Full Feature Test</h1>


<div id="highcharts-pie-container" style="width: 80%; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>


<p>Date Picker Example:</p>
<input type="text" id="datepicker" class="form-control" style="width: 200px; margin-bottom: 20px;">


<p>Bootstrap Select Example:</p>
<select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-info" multiple title="Choose one or more">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
</select>


<p>Bootstrap Multiselect Example:</p>
<select id="example-multiselect" multiple="multiple" class="multiselect">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
</select>


<p>Bootstrap Switch Example:</p>
<input type="checkbox" id="switch" checked data-toggle="switch">


<p>Bootstrap Tags Input Example:</p>
<input type="text" value="Amsterdam,Washington,Sydney" data-role="tagsinput">


<p>Jasny Bootstrap File Upload Example:</p>
<div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="form-control" data-trigger="fileinput">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file fileinput-exists"></i>
            <span class="fileinput-filename"></span>
        </div>
        <span class="input-group-addon btn btn-default btn-file">
            <span class="fileinput-new">Select file</span>
            <span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span>
            <input type="file" name="...">
        </span>
        <a href="#" class="input-group-addon btn btn-default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove</a>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
echo "<p>Current Time: " . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "</p>";
?>
<script src="dist/ui.bundle.js"></script>


<script>


</script>
</body>
</html>

Any suggestions would be helpful
The issue arises from this import 'bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js'; I tried to make sure jquery loads first which it is, but it doesnt work and i keep getting Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "fn", e is undefined when i import my ui.bundle.js

Possible reasons for this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined


invalid reference to the file addresses or missing files.
Duplicate reference to the Jquery
Overriding $ sign of Jquery in 3rd party libraries.
Using Jquery functions before inserting Jquery.
Using deprecated syntax for load,error,unload on WINDOW element in jquery without on

